# Validación en Laravel para recibir una de dos palabras

Tags: laravel, regex, validación

Estoy intentando añadir una regla de validación para un campo, tendría que recibir una de dos palabras, en principio he intentado usar la regla:

```
'string|regex:(foo|baz)'
```

El error:

> local.ERROR: preg_match(): No ending matching delimiter ')' found

***Nota:** sin la regla `regex` puede hacerce con `in`:*

```
'string|in:foo,baz'
```

Entonces, quisiera saber como hacer lo mismo con `regex`.

Comment: Prueba pasar un [array](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-regex) con las reglas en vez de las reglas separadas por pipe `|` > Al usar los patrones `regex/not_regex`, puede ser necesario especificar reglas en una matriz en lugar de usar delimitadores `|`..

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la clase `Rule` para especificar los valores que deseas que coincida:

**Laravel**:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

Validator::make($data, [
    'zones' => [
        'required',
        Rule::in(['first-zone', 'second-zone']),
    ],
]);
```

Puedes encontrar más detalles de esta regla de validación en la documentación de laravel: [aquí](https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#rule-in).

Espero sea de ayuda, saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Este error

> `preg_match(): No ending matching delimiter`  ...  `found`

en el 99% de los casos (incluido el tuyo) significa que no estás usando bien los delimitadores del regex. En PHP, el regex tiene que estar marcado con un caracter especial al inicio y al final del patrón. Muchas veces se usa `/`, por costumbre, pero se puede usar cualquier caracter no alfanumérico (https://www.php.net/manual/es/regexp.reference.delimiters.php).

Si modificás el patrón agregando los delimitadores, va a funcionar:

```
$patron = '/texto1|texto2/';
```